# Why do I get the error: Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher

Tags: api, google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation

I tried to start my app, but I get a error... I intigrated `google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.2` and `geolocator: ^2.1.0`. So one of this has to be the problem, but I don't understand what the error means.

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

But in my `build.gradl` I have the line: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` and this is higher then 1.2.71

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I found a solution thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the geolocator version `geolocator: ^5.1.3`